# Unable to create a custom field of type Social Media (OpenGraph)

Tags: sitefinity

I am implementing a social share feature in to my website which has been created using sitefinity CMS.

For that I have created MVC widget which consist of the code to share via twitter, linkedin and so on. I have referred the following link to implement the same.

https://www.progress.com/blogs/make-your-website-content-shareable-with-social-media-sharing-buttons

To enrich the shared content I need to use open graph custom fields which I need to add on the page where the social share widget is used. However, when I go on to create custom field from page grid I cannot find a type "Social Media (OpenGraph)" inside the type dropdown list.

Note:Version I am using is Progress Sitefinity CMS 11.0.6701.0 Enterprise Edition and checked SEO and OpenGraph properties from settings in backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OpenGraph field type has been added to Pages in Sitefinity version 11.1

See here: https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/111/release-notes